# Inserting a UTC offset datetime into SQL changes the time - Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, timezone, utc

I have a date 2015-03-11T08:43:19.7810000-05:00 the I am inserting into a MSSQL2008 database table datetime field.

I have verified my SQL Database is currently on daylight savings.

The East Coast of the USA is -5 offset.

Immediately upon inserting into SQL the time changes to 9:43am, adding one hour.

This would tell me some UTC or time zone conversion is not working.

I have even had my DBAs look at this and cannot figure it out.

I believe we should be storing datetime with UTC offset, but cannot figure out why this just started happening after the DST change last weekend.

Thanks.

Comment: yes, but the east coast is now in DST, which is effectively UTC-4, hence your one hour difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the offset persisted, you'll need to store it into a `datetimeoffset` field.

`datetime` fields do not save the offset.  Because you provided one, it is applied but then the time is being normalized to the local time zone, which is in UTC-4 for the date in question.